# Java libgdx Game Screens and rendering tile map

Tags: java, libgdx, tiled

I'm working on a 2D tiled game with Java and libGDX. I'm having problems implementing gamescreens. I'm trying to set the screen to gameScreen and start rendering tiles, but I'm getting a nullpointer exception on my camera and my renderer.

I think what's happening is that it's calling the render method before the create method for some reason. The create method is where the camera and renderer are set up.

This is my entry point, `gameClass`

```
package com.psillicoder.farmGame;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;

public class gameClass extends Game {   
    gameScreen gameScreen;

    public static final String TITLE="Farm Game";
    public static final int WIDTH=800,HEIGHT=600;

    @Override
    public void create() {  
        gameScreen = new gameScreen(this);
        setScreen(gamaeScreen); 
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        super.render();
    }
}
```

This is my `gameScreen` class:

```
package com.psillicoder.farmGame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;

public class gameScreen implements Screen {
    gameClass game; 

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
    private TiledMap map;

    SpriteBatch batch;  

    float unitScale = 1/16f;

    public gameScreen(gameClass game) {
        this.game = game; 
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        renderer.setView(camera);
        renderer.render();

        batch.begin();

        batch.end();    
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {      
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

        TiledMap map = new TmxMapLoader().load("tdmap1.tmx");
        OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map,unitScale);

        OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera();

        camera.setToOrtho(false,40,40);
        renderer.setView(camera);
        camera.update();

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose(); 
    }

    @Override 
    public void pause() {        
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {       
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        System.out.println("Disposed");
        batch.dispose();
        renderer.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Null pointer exceptions are not unique to game development. You just need some debugging skills to track this down.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of your `gameScreen` class does not initialize the `camera` and `renderer` fields, what you're initializing in the `show` method are method-local variables with the same names. That's why they're `null` when you're in the `render` method.

Try changing

```
OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map,unitScale);
OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera();
```

to

```
renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map,unitScale);
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
```

in the `show` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void create() {  
    gameScreen = new gameScreen(this);
    setScreen(gamaeScreen); 
}
```

Is the setScreen(gamaeScreen) a typo (gamaeScreen) ???